# How to use a single variable instead of passing multiple Arguments in Python

Tags: python

Say for example if I have a method which takes multiple inputs like below:

```
def SumOf(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3):
    Sum = Arg1+Arg2+Arg3
    return sum
```

I have the values of Arg1, Arg2, Arg3 in a list and I want to access the method

```
Arguments = Arg1 + "," +  Arg2 + "," + Arg 3
```

I want to use the variable Arguments to call the method SumOf

`SumOf(Arguments)`

But I get the following error:

```
SumOf() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Note: The above is just an example, I need this for executing different methods based on the method name and arguments.

Please help.

Comment: SumOf function should return Sum (capital s). I'm not able to edit it. why edit requires atleast 6 letters?

Comment: What does this have to do with wxPython or webdriver?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Arguments = 1, 2, 3
SumOf(*Arguments)
```

(*) operator will unpack the arguments to multiple parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like there's quite a few issues with your code. The line...

```
Arguments = Arg1 + "," +  Arg2 + "," + Arg3
```

...suggests `Arg1`, `Arg2` and `Arg3` are strings, which you're trying to concatenate into a single, comma-separated, string.

In order for the `SumOf` function to work, it will need to be passed integer values, so if `Arg1`, `Arg2` and `Arg3` are strings, you'll need to convert them to integers first with the `int()` function, and pack them into a tuple, with something like...

```
Arguments = (int(Arg1), int(Arg2), int(Arg3))
```

...at which point you can call the function with either...

```
SumOf(*Arguments)
```

...or...

```
apply(SumOf, Arguments)
```

Additionally, you'll need to change the line...

```
return sum
```

...to...

```
return Sum
```

...otherwise you'll end up returning a reference to Python's built-in `sum()` function.